# Pronunciation of "ый"

Tags: произношение

I'm having a **very** hard time understanding this pronunciation.
Is it safe to assume that **ый** sounds like *ey* in *hey* ?

Take the word *сильный* for instance,
the pronunciation on [forvo](https://forvo.com/word/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9/#ru) is slightly different than the one on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), which one is correct?

Comment: Wiktionary uses speech engine and at forvo you listen to live humans. Forvo's records sound more natural.

Comment: @AlexVB are you sure? It doesn't sound robotic at all

Comment: The way it pronounce "ый" made me think this. But now I think I was wrong. There are articles which have a transcription, but don't have a sound sample.

Comment: Wiktionary's audio has a weird noise at the end. Forvo pronunciations are cleaner and sound more natural.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All three of forvo are correct, while Wiktionary sounds as сильн**и**й.

*Hey* does not sound to me as a safe replacement of *ый*. As far as I know, the sound Ы does not exist in English. Have a look at this nice lesson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB61Fi1LluY

Comment: That's what I thought, it's very similar to сильний indeed, thank you!

Comment: For me, Wikitionary sounds OK.

Answer (score 3):

Only the last phoneme in `-ый` is similar to `ey` in `hey`, but not the entire syllable.

I'm not entirely clear what part of the syllable is a problem.

The divergence may be due to difference in expression of different speakers, without proper effort in articulation (like in fluent speech) it may sound as just `-ы` without `-й`, which at this position is very short anyway (not without a reason the letter is named "short И"), getting reduced because the word stress is far removed from it.

I didn't notice it being pronounced as `-ий` in the clips.

The word contains both vowels с**И**льн**Ы**й and in the Wiktionary clip difference in their pronunciation is apparent. `И` softens consonants which precede it (save for `Ц/Ж/Ш`, which in combination `ЦИ/ЖИ/ШИ` are pronounced as `ЦЫ/ЖЫ/ШЫ`) whereas in the clip `Н` before `-ый` isn't softened, which would be the case had the ending been pronounced as `-ий`.

If you're trying to understand how `ы` is to be properly pronounced, i'd suggest taking notice of how English `duh` interjection is pronounced, because its vowel is quite close.